# Finding SOC (Soil Organic Carbon) index using Sentinel 2 (L2A)

Tags: sentinel-2, sentinel

I am currently working on a project to find SOC (Soil organic carbon) using satellite imaging from Sentinel 2 L2A. Is there any way for calculating soil organic carbon index using the Sentinel L2A's bands? Any formula or procedure that leads to the solution?